# other ways to solve the problem 'package not available'

Tags: r

I would like to use the ArchTest function from the 'FinTS' package, so that I have tried and install the package and I have got the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘FinTS’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

I would rather not have to install an older R version. My question is whether there are other ways to sort out the problem.
I would be grateful if someone could help me with this little issue.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: Thank you, Alaleh A, I have found the answer there